# Game Theory- Bertrand Problem

Tags: game-theory, economics

I'm supposed to find the subgame Nash equilibrium but I'm stuck. Would appreciate the help.

We were presented with a Cournot duopoly problem (select quantities) and are basically asked to solve it as a Bertrand problem (select prices). Firm 1 and Firm 2 compete to sell a good, and they have advertising budgets.

$Q = a - p$ where a is advertising and p is the price. 
The firms' costs are $2a^3 / 81$

Therefore, total profits are: $(a-p)p - 2a^3 / 81$

Given the information, I'm asked to find the subgame perfect equilibrium. With this I'm supposed to derive and set equal to 0.

Because the lowest price receives all the customers, I'm going to assume that each firm will sell at the same price- is this wrong to do? Therefore, I'll get:

$(a-p)0.5p - 2a^3 / 81$ and the derivative with respect to p should be: $0.5a - p=0$ This makes the optimal $ p = 2a$ right?

To find the optimal a, we must therefore do:
$4a^2 -2a^3/81=0$ but this makes $a = 162$

That doesn't really make sense at all. What did I do wrong? Appreciate the help

Comment: Not sure I follow.  where did the $.5$ in your expression for the profit?  It's not there the first time, but appears the second.  Also the solution to $.5a-p=0$ is $p=\frac 12a$, not $2a$ (this is true regardless of the multiplicative $.5$.  And, most importantly, why would you set the profit to $0$?

Comment: Sorry, guess I skipped ahead. I got $(a-p)0.5p$ by setting the derivative of profits to 0. $ap - p^2 - 2a^3/81$ derived is $a - 2p = 0$

Comment: The first expression you give for total profits is $(a-p)p-\frac {2a^3}{81}$.  the second expression you give is $(a-p)0.5p-\frac {2a^3}{81}$.  I just wondered where that $0.5$ came from.  Are you assuming the two firms split the revenue evenly or something?  With either expression you get $p=\frac 12 a$ via the derivative, not $p=2a$ as you have it.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant- they split it evenly as the equilibrium would be to match the same price. Solving as $p = 1/2 a$ gets me $81/8$. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: I don't understand why you set profit to zero.  Mind you, I don't know what a Bertrand Problem is, nor what a Cournot duopoly is.  Is the idea that the two firms would compete to the point where profit was entirely eliminated?  Am I to assume that the other firm has the same profit structure (so that their ad budget is the same as ours)?  That seems unrealistic.  I can see where competition might force firms to lower price down to the bone, but I can't see why the two firms should spend exactly the same amount on marketing, etc.

Comment: To be clear: unit price is observable.  If you lower your price, I see that and I have to respond to it.  Ad budget is not observable.  What force would compel me to match you dollar for dollar?

Comment: I'm not setting profit to 0. I'm taking the derivative and setting to 0 (finding the max). Firm 1 has the advertising budget. It's just really confusing- I may have set up the problem wrong so would appreciate help in just getting put in the right direction

Comment: Yes...you are setting profit to $0$.  That's how you get $\frac {81}8$ isn't it?  The derivative calculation gives you $p=\frac 12a$ so profit is $\frac 14 a^2-\frac {2a^3}{81}$ and if I set that to $0$ I get $a =\frac {81}8$.  I just don't know why you'd set that to $0$.

Comment: I take the partial derivative of p and go from $0.5pa - 0.5p^2 - 2a^3/81$ to $0.5a - p =0$

Comment: Yes, I do understand how you get $p=\frac 12 a$ .  that doesn't tell you what $a$ is!!  To get that, it certainly appears that you set profit to zero.  How did you get it?

Comment: Oh, I see now. So I need to take the derivative of the second equation right? If $p = 1/2a$ my profit function is $ 1/4a^2 - 2a^3/81$ and that derived gives me $1/2a - 6a^2/81 = 0 $. So would the answer be $27/4$?

Comment: I have no idea why you would do that.  But, I must stress:  I don't know the economic methods you are invoking.  Presumably they tell you what equilibrium assumptions you are meant to make.

Comment: I'm just maximizing the profit function with respect to a. Doesn't that sound right?

Comment: But you did that when you got $p=\frac 12a$.  Without some additional assumption, that's as far as you can go.  Again, maybe the economic theory you are employing tells you what the equilibrium profit should look like.  If so, fine.

Comment: Just to say, the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cournot_competition) on Cournot competition suggests that all quantities are common  knowledge (including the costs spent by each firm) but there isn't generally an assumption that marginal costs are equal.  Demand is fixed and the  firms then seek the Nash equilibrium to decide how much to produce (again, assuming that their competitors production is common knowledge).

Comment: Does that mean the setup to my problem is wrong? Know you're not an expert, would appreciate help just making sure I'm on the right track..

Comment: Based on my (very sketchy) scan of the definitions, I think you are meant to be solving for two quantities...$q_1,q_2$ produced by the two firms.  The market then sets the price, $=Price(q_1,q_2)$.  Then you use the internal profit formulae to determine the Nash equilibrium.  That makes sense to me...but that doesn't mean I have it right!

Comment: How would you set up the problem? Thanks for the help I appreciate it

Comment: If my reading is correct, then I am not sure there is enough information here (which might suggest that my reading is incorrect, I understand).  I need to understand what my competitor's profit structure looks like (might be the same thing, only with a different ad budget) and I need to know what the market clearing price function is (a model for that might well be part of the general theory). I'd seek clarification from whomever set the problem.

Comment: Yeah I set a time to meet with my professor, this is getting crazy lol. Thanks for the help I'll keep you posted

Comment: Good luck.  If you think of it, edit your question to include the resolution with your professor.

Comment: @DickThompson Quote:" I'm asked to find the subgame perfect equilibrium. " Who is the first mover ?

Comment: Firm 1 is the first mover- can you please help me figure this out?